# Auto resize div height based on window width

Tags: html, height, media-queries

I can't seem to get this. I have a media query of 590px screen width to have a div with this CSS

```
#slider {
width:100%;
height:250px;
background-color:#FF0000;
```

However now I want to have the height adjust smaller (from 250px) as you keep reducing the screen width (working with a responsive design). Auto, 100% won't work because I need to specify a starting height of 250px; and max-height does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily using [jQuery](http://jquery.com) by storing the window width in a variable and then applying this variable in the element's height:

```
function changeHeight() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    $("div").css({
        "height": width
    });
}
window.addEventListener('resize', changeHeight);
changeHeight();
```

Since this javascript code changes the element's height using CSS, you can even apply CSS `transition`s to make the animation smoother.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/BA8Vr/6/)

[**JSFiddle Demo using CSS transitions**](http://jsfiddle.net/TiagoMarinho/BA8Vr/7/)

Comment: change the line 4 with this: `"height":Math.max(width, X);` and change `X` with the minimal height you want. You can learn more about the JavaScript `max()` method here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_max.asp.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put both of the CSS properties

```
max-height:250px;
height:100%;
```

Comment: tried this. replacing height:250px; with what you have and the containers height is 0 meaning it doesn't show.

Answer (score 1):

There is a terrible, terrible hack to do this. But it usually works out smoother than using JavaScript to size the element.

Take advantage of the fact that padding values (event vertical ones) are always relative to the container width. Set a `padding-top` with a percentage value (you'll have to calculate it yourself because you didn't specify what you consider "normal screen width") on the slider element itself, or if that messes things up, put an extra element inside and set the padding on that. This of course pushes all normal flow content down, so you'll have to absolutely position them on top of the magic padding div.

Plus, unless you're absolutely positioning, `width: 100%` on a block element probably does nothing useful in your case.

Comment: works in theory but the inner element div doesn't show because all I see is the padding space.

Comment: To fix my width from the height with children inside, that works with : padding: 0.0001% with me. Thx for the tip